# how to fetch data from elastic search in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using NODE JS with elastic search DB .
I am using this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch
I have this collection in my elastic search DB

```
[
  {
    "_index": "products",
    "_id": "wZRh3n8Bs9qQzO6fvTTS",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "laptop issues",
      "description": "laptop have issue present in according"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "products",
    "_id": "wpRh3n8Bs9qQzO6fvzQM",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "buy mobile",
      "description": "mobile is in Rs 250"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "products",
    "_id": "w5Rh3n8Bs9qQzO6fvzTz",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "laptop payment",
      "description": "laptop payment is given in any way"
    }
  }
]
```

now I am planning to fetch data from elastic DB . when I am passing "LAP" or "lap" . it is giving me blank array or `[]` array why ? "lap" is present in all object

I am doing like that

```
 const result= await client.search({
      index: 'products',
      query: {
        match_phrase: {
            description: "lap"
        }
      }
```

where I am doing wrong . I need all result where **lap**  keywords is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match query is not working because you are trying to search partial character of `laptop` term.

You can use [Prefix Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) for single term like below:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "title": {
        "value": "lap"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to search for phrase then you can use [Phrase Prefix Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html):

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "title": "lap"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to match only some of the word from query then you can use `match query` with `operator` set to `or`.

```json
POST querycheck/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "i have issues",
        "operator": "or"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank for answer . is it possible to search item . If i am doing `"title": "I have issues"` it will give this output having id `wZRh3n8Bs9qQzO6fvTTS ` because `issues` is present in title .

Comment: I have updated question, please check

Comment: thank almost correct.. but one point is missing I said if i search i have issu still I want to search element.. here is it giving me zero or 0 output